# Can`t change a color of navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Navbar doesnt change a background color, i tried to do bg/variant = dark/black , it doesnt change anything

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navbar,Container,Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Header extends Component{
    render() {
        return(
            < Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark"  >
                <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">My landing Page</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="/aboutMe" > About me</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/aboutUnivercity">  My Univercity</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/video">  My videos</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/myMotivate">  MyMotivate</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }

}
```

Source if needed:
https://github.com/aokhar/SumPract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add bootstrap in your react app.

In your terminal using yarn type:

```
yarn add bootstrap
```

Then at the top of your js file add:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

After this hopefully all the colors will render.

Comment: It give me a error: Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: You must be making your js file outside of src folder. Put your js file inside src folder.It will work.

Comment: it is in a src folder

Comment: I would need to see your file. Without it I can't help you. Post it in a question.

Comment: post link to github, if needed to know i use WebStorm

Comment: In your import you have import "/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
Remove the slash make it like this: import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
It will work.